# How to configure template to route to a different object id from DetailView?

Tags: django

Here is a very simple reference of my django app..

```
# models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.ManytoManyField(Address)
    def get_absolute_url(self, **kwargs):
        ...

class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Here is my DetailView of Doctor model:

```
#views.py
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
```

WITHIN my HTML template of PersonDetailView, how can I access the url and object ID for Address?
Currently, if I try something like `{% url 'address_detail' object.id %}`, the object id is referencing the Person model and not the Address.

I am trying to access a url for the address model because I want to the user to be able to access Address's class-based UpdateView FROM the PersonDetailView.

Answer (score 0):

Your `address` is a ManyToManyField, meaning each user could have multiple addresses. If that's not your intention, change that to a ForeignKey instead.

Then you can use `{% url 'address_detail' object.address.id %}` or preferably the faster `{% url 'address_detail' object.address_id %}` (which uses the id field backing all Django ForeignKeys).

If you really *did* intend for a many-to-many relationship, I'd recommend renaming the field to `addresses`, to make it clear there are several. Do note though that using a ManyToManyField means each address can be associated with more than one user. If you don't want *that*, then declare the address model to have a foreign key to the User:

```
class Address(...):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='addresses')
```

No matter whether you have

- `addresses = models.ManyToManyField()` on the user,
  or
- the above `user = (...related_name='addresses')` on the address,

accessing the addresses in the template is then

```
{% for address in user.addresses.all %}
  {% url 'address_detail' address.id %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, I did intend for a m2m relationship. Once I rename to addresses, do you know a possible way I could access the UpdateView of the Address model from the PersonDetailView?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want one address to be able to be associated with multiple users? Or do you want one user to have multiple addresses?

Comment: Yeah, so the Person model is actually a Doctor model, where many doctors can have the same address (because they use the same facility), and one address can be used for multiple doctors. Doctors may also have their own private offices or remote locations associated with them, so I think it makes sense for me to go this route. 
eventually, I would like for users to click on an address and see all the doctors associated with the address, too.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense then (though you may want to consider a `Location` model the doctors are associated with, maybe?). Either way, I augmented the answer – please have a look!

Comment: Thank you so so so much, it works just fine! I just need to figure out how to dynamically redirect the url back to the Person model once the I've updated the address model (because it won't always be back to the Doctor model, it could be a patient model, etc.). I appreciate you for taking your time to help me out! :)

Comment: You might want to pass that as a query parameter or somesuch then, e.g. `{% url 'address_detail' address.id %}?source=doctor-{% user.id %}`, if that'd work for you...

Comment: Yeah, I set the parameters <a href="{% url 'address_update' a.id %}?next={% url 'doctor_detail' object.id %}"> in my person detail view, and it's still throwing an ImproperlyConfigured error saying no url to redirect to/set a get_absolute_url which is weird.

Comment: That's probably another issue unrelated to this. The URL template tag shouldn't throw that.